# How to reapply for Ubuntu membership after it expired?

Tags: ubuntu-membership

In the [Membership FAQ](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Membership/FAQ#Do_I_need_to_reapply_at_some_point.3F_How_long_will_I_be_an_Ubuntu_Member.3F) it says that being an Ubuntu Member is a lifelong thing. But it doesn't mention what happens when somebody doesn't renew the subscription on launchpad.

So, if 2 years since my membership passed, I miss the email, forget about it or don't want to renew the subscription at that time, and then I want to renew my membership, what is the process?

Comment: Are you in this situation now and if so, what have you tried so far and what has been the problems you've encountered?  You tried logging in at Launchpad?

Comment: I am not in this situation. But I get asked a lot. I know the membership council can renew the subscription, but I don't know what the process is to ask them to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the rejoin process documented:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Membership/Rejoining